# waf error when building pybindgen on Mac OS 10.7

Tags: python, waf, pybindgen

I am trying to build Pybindgen on Mac OS 10.7. Lion Everything works fine on Ubuntu to compare but...

On OS X the waf installer (Pybindgen uses waf to build and install) chokes on this:

```
Checking for program python              : ok /usr/bin/python 
Checking for Python version >= 2.3       : ok 2.7.1 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : ok /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program cpp                 : ok /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : ok /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : ok /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for program g++,c++             : ok /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for library python2.7           : not found 
Checking for library python2.7           : not found 
Checking for library python27            : not found 
Checking for program python2.7-config    : ok /usr/bin/python2.7-config 
Checking for header Python.h             : Could not find the python development headers 
 error: the configuration failed (see '/Users/kosta/Downloads/pybindgen-0.15.0/build/config.log')
```

=> BUT I am 100% sure I have at least Python.h in my Mac SDk ... I know it is there... I just dont know how to make sure waf finds it... There is a function in waf called check_python_headers which seems to be the problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you append the content of the logfile? That would surely help.

Comment: I have this same issue.  Had one like it with a cmake project as well but I was easily able to set the python header location and it found it. No such luck on wap thus far.